# How to upgrade a smart contract logic?

Tags: smart-contract, upgrade

I deployed a smart contract to a substrate chain. How can I upgrade the `smart contract's` logic to a newer version?

Edit: I'm using `ink!` and deployed on `Shibuya` (Astar testnet)

Comment: What smart contract eDSL are you using? (Solidity, ink!, ..) 
On which parachain did you deploy?

Comment: ink! on Shibuya (Astar testnet) @P.Ossun

Answer (score 13):

You currently have two options for writing upgradeable smart contracts in ink!. For both of them we have example contracts. They differ in the following key characteristics.

The [`forward-calls`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/upgradeable-contracts/forward-calls) example implements a classic forward-pattern:

- The contract forwards any call that does not match a selector of itself to another contract. The address of this "another contract" can be changed by the instantiator of the contract  (there is a notion of "admin" in the example contract).
- The other contract needs to be deployed on-chain.
- State is stored in the storage of the contract to which calls are forwarded.

The [`delegate-calls`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/upgradeable-contracts/delegate-calls) example on the other hand utilizes an API similar to Ethereum's `delegatecall` function:

- The contract executes any call that does not match a selector of itself with the code of another contract. The address of this "another contract" can be changed by the instantiator of the contract (there is a notion of "admin" in the example contract).
- The other contract does not need to be deployed on-chain.
- State is stored in the storage of the originally called contract.

Future versions of [OpenBrush](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts) (a library similar to OpenZeppelin, but for ink!) will contain support for the diamond pattern, another way of building upgradeable contracts.

Comment: Isn't pallet-contracts going to support `set_code`?

Comment: @h4x3rotab Yes, that's correct, thanks for bringing that up! There's currently already a PR to include it in ink!. I'll update the above answer once it's merged.

Comment: FYI since you mentioned it, yesterday we released [OpenBrush 1.6](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/releases/tag/v1.6.0) with the diamond standard implementation

Answer (score 7):

You can have a look at Parity upgradeable example:
https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/upgradeable-contracts (fixed broken link)

It follows proxy pattern of OpenZeppelin